# validate editText on buttonclick event

Tags: android, validation, events, buttonclick

I am new in android programming and still learning. for practice i started to create a very simple and basic app which calculate age on button click which take birth year as an input.
i manage to get it working and want to do some validation on it. like i have done validating that the value we provide should not be more than current year and i successfully done that.

Now my problem is that i also want to put validation that if no input is been made and button is pressed then it should alert the user by Toast. So far i have tried doing but every time i press button without anything in editText the app just crash.

here's my code.

```
        calcAge.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



             if(dob > year){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Provide valid Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

             else if(String.valueOf(dob) == null){

                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Provide Some Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }

            else{


                dob = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(inAge.getText()));
                currentYear.setText("Your Curret Year is :- " + year);
                yourYear.setText("Your Birth Year is :- "+ dob);

            int a = year-dob;

            finalAns.setText("Your Age is :- " + a);

            inAge.setText("");

            }



        }
    });
```

above code is of button click. Please provide with some solution

I have also tried putting editText1.getText().toString.trim().lenght()==0 in if condition but that also didn't worked and app just crashes.

Answer (score 1):

try this on button click listner

```
calcAge.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (yourEdittext.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    yourEdittext.setError(getString("filed can't be empty"));
                    yourEdittext.requestFocus();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Provide Some Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }
        });
```

Comment: @MustakimKhalifa You're welcome. Don't forget to upvote and mark one of the answers as accepted so it's clear to others that your question doesn't need more answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
String dob = yourEditText.getText().toString();
```

then check it like this:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(dob)) {
            //show toast
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do validation like this :

```
 doneDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(validationDetails()){
                        //If get all data do Action
                        }else{
                            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Field Missing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
```

This is the validation part method:

```
 private boolean validationDetails() {

                    if (userNameET.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        userNameET.setError("Enter Patient Name");
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (ageET.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        ageET.setError("Enter Age ");
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (gender.getSelectedItem().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Select Gender",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this on your button click :

```
if ( yourEditText.getText().toString().equal("")) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Give Some Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On button click, you are checking first if dob is greater than a year. which is not correct. First, check if dob is null or empty. then check for if greater than year

```
If (dob == null && dob.isEmplty){
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Provide Some Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if(dob > year){
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Provide valid Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
//do what ever you want
}
```